# Blender equivalent of GIMP Levels tool

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have been trying to replicate the effect of [Gimp Levels tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-levels.html) in blender but could not quite get the same result as in GIMP.
My attempt is summarized on the picture below, I tried to remap the values to a new range but that did not really work.
Any idea how to achieve the same effect?

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 1):

The upper part of the Levels tool, "*Input Levels*",

[image]

should be equivalent to mapping the "*Value*" channel of the input image to the output image through a *ColorRamp*:

[image]

*Separate HSVA*, then recombine them with *Combine HSVA*, but add a *Color Ramp* between the *V* sockets. In the *Color Ramp* add a slider ("+") and moving the three sliders should behave the same as in *Levels*.